# Thoughts on Continuum Hypothesis proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

First, I'll review my knowledge of 'what is $\aleph _1$'. My understanding is based on the video https://youtu.be/SrU9YDoXE88

So, say we list out the natural numbers in an infinite list. Now this set has cardinality $\aleph _0$ and order-type $\omega$. Then we take out every even number from the list and list them below our original list (the original list is only left with the odds now) Now this 'list of two lists' still has the cardinality $\aleph _0$ because the members of both lists come from the set of naturals and both lists can be combined to give back naturals. But this 'list of two lists' has order type $2\omega$.

We can keep doing this to produce new order types. We can take out every member at an even position in the second list and list those below our second list. This list of 'three lists' has an order type $3\omega$.

Continuing this, we'll have a list of infinite lists of cardinality still $\aleph _0$, but order type $\omega\cdot \omega=\omega^2$. We can still keep doing this to get order-types of $\omega^{\omega}$, $^{\omega}\omega$, etc. The first order-type which we cannot get by just re-ordering the naturals like this is $\omega _1$ and since we can't get there by re-ordering the naturals, then it has to have a higher cardinality than the naturals ($\aleph _1$).

This is my understanding of $\aleph _1$. Now my proof:

We first list out the countable list of real numbers of the form $2^{-n}$, where $n$ is a whole number ($1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}.....$). This list has cardinality $\aleph _0$ and order type $\omega$. From each member of this list, we'll generate another list, so that we have a list of lists.

From each member $2^{-n}$, we generate the infinite list : $2^{-n}, \frac{2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)}}{2}, \frac{\frac{2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)}}{2} + 2^{-(n+1)}}{2},.....$, and so on.

Now we have an infinite list of infinite lists of cardinality $\aleph _0$ and order type $\omega ^2$. From each member of the sub-infinite lists, we can again use a process similar to above to generate an infinite list. For example, the first two members of the first sub-infinite list are $1$ and $\frac{3}{4}$. We can product the following infinite list from $1$:

$1, \frac{1+\frac{3}{4}}{2}, \frac{\frac{1+\frac{3}{4}}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}{2},.....$ and so on.

So continuing this, we can get higher order types $\omega^{3}, \omega^{\omega}, ^{\omega}\omega$....

The first order-type we can't get by continuing this process has to have the cardinality $\aleph _1$.

We see that we can get arbitrarily close to any real number in the range $(0,1)$ by using this process. Since we can get arbitrarily close to any of the members of $(0,1)$, so there can't be any set with cardinality in-between of the the cardinality of $(0,1)$ and the cardinality of naturals.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep doing this"? You can keep doing it for $k\omega$, but then what? You can only go finitely far with this process, since you have to specify it each time.

Comment: The (countable) rationals are dense in the reals, so can get arbitrarily close to any real with them.  Why does that mean that the cardinal of the reals is no greater than the next cardinal after the rationals?  You have not justified that claim at all.  We know it might be, but Paul Cohen proved that if ZFC is consistent it is also consistent that the cardinal of the reals is something else.

Comment: What Vsauce doesn't mention in that video is that is has been proven that the Continuum Hypothesis cannot be proven to be true or false.

Comment: @RossMillikan In the proof, we generate higher and higher order types. By definition, the limit of this process is an order type so high that we can't get there by continuing this process, and it has cardinality $\aleph _1$. If we're getting as close to reals as we like, then reals have to be the limit of the process.

Comment: But the reals are not defined as order types.  They are usually defined as cuts of the rationals.

Comment: @RossMillikan But reals are a set. I want to correct my sentence : "By definition, the limit of this process is a set of order type so high that we can't get there by continuing this process, and it has cardinality $\aleph _1$". In the process, we are generating sets of higher and higher order types, so the limit is also a set.

Comment: It is true that $\aleph_1$ is the supremum of all the countable ordinals.  I don't see any connection with the reals there.  The reals do not care about order types.

Comment: @DonThousand We can use the replacement axiom, right? That's how they produced order types $\omega^{\omega}, \omega ^2$ in the video. So we generate the infinite list from one of the members, and then use replacement axiom.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm saying that, by definition of $\aleph _1$, it's the cardinality of the set we can never get by continuing the process in my post. It's the limit of the process. It's like how we never reach $\aleph _0$ by continuing to add members in a countable set. The set of real numbers is also the limit of the same process, as we can get as close to reals as we like using the process. So the set of real numbers must have the cardinality $\aleph _1$.

Comment: All your order types are just rationals, at least in the examples you show.  You don't add any numbers by considering the order types.  It is just another way of representing the rationals we know and love.  But there is nothing saying there is not a subset of the reals of cardinality between the rationals and the reals.  We can't demonstrate one because it is consistent with ZFC that there is none, but we also can't demonstrate there is not one.  Your order types do not show there are not more limits of sequences of rationals.

Comment: @RossMilikan How can there be two limits of this thing? Maybe we should add an axiom to ZFC that there can be only one limit to a process like this. It's unintuitive for this process to have two limits and we don't want to work with such a model of sets.

Comment: The gap is between “Since we can get arbitrarily close to any member of $(0,1)$” to “there can’t be any set with cardinality in between the cardinality of $(0,1)$ and the naturals.” If this implication held, then why are you doing your whole song and dance? The rationals are already arbitrarily close to every member of $(0,1)$; why does that, by itself, not tell you that there is no set of cardinality strictly between that of $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ and that of $(0,1)$? Hint: it does not. Your construction does nothing but create a smokescreen behind which that logical jump tries to hide.

Comment: @RyderRude "Maybe we should add an axiom to ZFC that there can be only one limit to a process such as this." Okay, let's do it. We'll need to have the committee meeting over zoom though.

Comment: Between any two distinct reals there is a rational and between any distinct rationals there is a real.  So, they are interleaved and hence the same size rather like the odd and even integers.  I am not really claiming this, just illustrating that intuition often fails with infinite sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that's not true. The whole construction is there to produce higher and higher order types, so that we are approaching  $\aleph _1$ (but can never get there using the process). That's the very definition of $\aleph _1$. Only after that I use the fact that the construction can get arbitrarily close to reals, so the limit (and hence the set with cardinality $\aleph _1$) has to be the set of reals itself.

Comment: @RyderRude You are paying a lot of attention to your newfound understanding of $\aleph_1$ but not enough to your lack of understanding of what it means technically for $\aleph_1$ to be in one-to-one correspondence with the reals. It's the part that you do "only after that" that is the problem. Neither the infer "so the limit... has to be the reals itself" nor the subinference "and hence the set with cardinality $\aleph_1$" make any sense.

Comment: I wrote a commentary on this video, http://karagila.org/2016/vsauce-on-cardinals-and-ordinals/

Comment: @RyderRude: What isn’t true? That all you are doing is listing rationals? That the exact same argument could have been made with the rationals in their usual order? it doesn’t matter *how* you list them, unless you actually **produce all reals** *in* your process (actually produce them, not just get “arbtirarily close”) then all you are doing is throwing up a lot of smoke and then making a logical lewap at the end.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "That the exact same argument could have been made with the rationals in their usual order?" Yes, this isn't true. Rationals aren't even well-ordered in their usual order. How can we produce order types from that? "unless you actually produce all reals in your process (actually produce them, not just get “arbtirarily close”)" No need to do that. I can use the idea of limits here.

Comment: @RyderRude: The part of the argument that could be made with the rationals in their usual order is “I get arbitrarily close to any real”. As to your final comment, it’s absolute, complete, and utter nonsense. You aren’t doing real analysis, you are doing set theory. In set theory, “limits” in this sense means **unions**. And in a union, there is nothing in the union that isn’t in one of the sets that are part of the union. The fact that you do not realize this only shows you are well over your head and do not understand what needs to be done in this context.

Comment: @RyderRude: The key part of your argument isn’t that you are constructing order types. The key part of your argument is when you try to go from “I’m listing rationals” to “I’m listing all real number” (where ‘listing’ means ‘bijecting with some well-order type). That key part is where you wave your hands mightily and rely on some sort of “approximation” argument. But that kind of approximation is analytic, not set-theoretic, and analytically, the same is true for the rationals in their usual order (not a well-order, but irreleavant to your “approximation” step).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really just an elaboration of what's been said by others in the comments...

As commenters have noted, all you seem to have done here is put subsets of the rationals into various countable order-types. You haven't been very explicit about how to do this, but it's certainly true that the rationals can be put into any countable order type. The reason is trivial: the rationals are countable.

But then you jump the gun and say that since you imagine carrying the process to larger and larger countable order types will eventually produce a rational arbitrarily close to a given real, that means that there are no more than $\aleph_1$ reals.

I think you're imagining that the you are covering all of the reals by the various countable order types in this way, but notice there are no real numbers on your list at all, only rationals. (Also, there are a ton of different numbers on each level so it's unclear how you mean to claim there's a surjection from $\aleph_1$ here...)

Commenters have offered a bit of a reductio ad absurdum that I'll echo. There was no reason you needed the first stage in your process (order type $\omega$) to be $2^{-1}, 2^{-2},\ldots.$ The rationals are countable. You could have chosen an enumeration of the full list of rationals in type $\omega$. So, in one stage, you get arbitrarily close to every real number. So the reals are countable? (Or worse... they have cardinality 1??)

**EDIT**

I seem to have misunderstood your argument. The idea instead seems to be that somehow since you can produce a rational at each point of each countable ordinal, in some way that is vaguely "continuous" that the limit when you iterate this over the countable ordinals will be an ordering of type $\omega_1$ which has a real number at each point, and also contains every real number since you can somehow guarantee each real number is 'approached' (and thus "converged to").

There is a lot of handwaving here, to the point that this is almost too vague to form a clear picture of and refute. So instead I'll ask you to try to fill in the gaps... which real number is assigned to a given countable ordinal? Which real number is assigned to $\omega^2$ here? Can you actually show that for every real number, there is some countable ordinal that it is assigned to under the "limit"?

I don't anticipate you will have success here. As others have note, it has been proven some time ago that one cannot prove the CH from ZFC, much less from real analytic sort construction such as you're trying to do here.

Comment: "So, in one stage, you get arbitrarily close to every real number. So the reals are countable? (Or worse... they have cardinality 1??)". That's not what I inferred from that. In fact, I accept that I'm not getting any irrationals on my lists by using this process. Instead, I'm getting arbitrarily close to irrationals. So the first 'order type' I can't "reach" by continuing this has to be the reals itself, all because I'm never getting there by continuing this process but am getting as close as I want. That is the limit.

Comment: @RyderRude I made an edit.

Comment: "Which real number is assigned to ω2 here?" But real-numbers are not supposed to be well-ordered, right? So I don't think $\omega ^2$ is assigned to any real number in the limit. However, prior to the limit (when we are iterating my process), $\omega ^2$ gets assigned to a different real (rational real) at each step (as we generate new lists from each member of the former list).

Comment: "it has been proven some time ago that one cannot prove the CH from ZFC" This is why I won't try to use ZFC. It has to be an incomplete theory of the world of sets. It might be missing some of the axioms about their intuitive properties. So I'll make up some intuitive properties (which hopefully people agree with) and derive CH from that. It's like how the Axiom of Choice got added later because it made intuitive sense.

Comment: @RyderRude Okay, but at the end of the day **you need a bijection between $\omega_1$ and $\mathbb R$.** In other words a one-to-one correspondence between the countable ordinals and the real numbers. That is what it means for the continuum hypothesis to hold. Ostensibly, your construction, if it does what you says it does, should give such a correspondence. Thus it makes sense to ask, which real number is assigned to $\omega^2$ under this correspondence.

Comment: @RyderRude You are right that it would have to be a matter of new axioms. But as for the rest, I'll just say I respect the optimism you're bringing to this, but to me it sounds naive, especially as you don't seem to grasp some key concepts yet. Incidentally, for a semi-serious example of an 'intuitive new axiom' that implies CH, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry . But note nobody thinks this solves the problem.  (Also, that's historically wrong about AC... it was there at the very beginning, at least if you count the very beginning as Zermelo's axioms ca 1908.)